# systemd.networkd DHCP server: assign static addresses to DHCP clients

Tags: dhcp, systemd-networkd

I want to switch from `isc-dhcp-server` to `systemd.networkd` but I couldn't find any information about assigning static IP addresses (based on MAC) in `systemd.networkd`. Is it possible to configure `systemd.networkd` DHCP server to assign static addresses to DHCP clients?

Comment: @Panki it can be configured to start a DHCP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got to read man pages more carefully. It's right there in `[DHCPSERVERSTATICLEASE]` section.